# knockoutjs modify objects within an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have this view model here :

```
var myObsArr = ko.observableArray();

var object1 = {attrA : 'hello', attrB : false};
var object2 = {attrA : 'world', attrB : true};

myObsArr.push(object1, object2);

var vm = {
    myObsArr : myObsArr
}
return vm;
```

I can get any value from this observableArray by doing for example : `myObsArr()[1].attrB`.

Is there any way I can **SET** those values like `myObsArr[1].attrB = false` , without doing any `remove` or `replace`??

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can set the values with : `myObsArr[1]().attrB = false` ... what is not working?

Comment: myObsArr()[1].attrB = false;

You appear to have forgotten the () ?

Comment: @nemesv `myObsArr[1]().attrB = false` doesnt work

Comment: Please be more specific and define "doesnt work"!

Comment: @nemesv "Uncaught TypeError: Object function observable()", it looks like the object doesnt exist.

Comment: Parenthesis first. Bad: myObsArr[1]().attrB Good: myObsArr()[1].attrB

Comment: at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html they said this "Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, **not the state of those objects**" so apparently you can not change objects inside an observableArray without making them observables.

Comment: @dafriskymonkey makes sense why the solution below was created then.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is too late... the correct syntax is `myObsArr()[1].attrB = false` just like when getting the value with `myObsArr()[1].attrB` http://jsfiddle.net/E6Ltk/

Comment: @nemesv yeah its correct it changes the state of the object but not the observableArray : in the "view" the `myObsArr()[1].attrB` will stay `true`

Comment: For that you need to make your attrB observable `var object2 = {attrA : 'world', attrB : ko.observable(true)};` and set it with: `myObsArr()[1].attrB(false)`

Comment: @nemesv lol, so this is what i was talking about, You must make attributes observables themselves, BECAUSE ko doesnt track changes inside the observableArray. I dont know why they make it this way, for me they make it complicated when they could make it simple.

Comment: as im learning ko im seeing that it is a wonderful tool, very powerful  , but it has some big probleme, for example : debugging ko is really a hard work.

Comment: So you asked your question wrong. I understand why you think it's complicated. When I was learning KO I also wanted to go Rambo and ko.observable everything. Now I think that complicated it would be if observableArray had done this. It's simpler and clearer to specify how every property should behave. And when I had gone further with my app I have every observable slightly different now, with extenders, subscribers, validation and postbox. Every ko.observable and ko.observableArray does its magic one level at a time, and thanks KO for not making a mess by taking everything it meets on its way.

Comment: @WojciechCzerniak You are probably right mate. I still have some misunderstanding about ko. Ill probably join ur idea when ill be more familiar with ko way of thinking.

Comment: but who the hell -1 me ?? and why ?? you dont want me to post questions anymore?? im trying to get at least 15 pts, i see its gonna be hard.

Comment: im trying to ask simple questions, tracking every changes in my posts regularly, being nice and polite. and this post cost me 20% of my SO points, sorry but im MAD.

Comment: Don't know, whoever -1 should comment why. It's easy to click, hard to explain. Don't worry about points. Just stay true to what you were doing. You can always fix your question.

Comment: @WojciechCzerniak thanks mate im new to SO and i wanted to go Rambo in this one too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle I found that has an interesting approach that looks like it does similar to what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/up8rB/

```
var items = [{
    Id: 1,
    Text: 'First item'
}, {
    Id: 2,
    Text: 'Second item'
}];

var observableItems = [
    new ItemViewModel(1, "First item"),
    new ItemViewModel(2, "Second item")
];

function ItemViewModel(id, text){
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Text = ko.observable(text);
}

var viewModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItemId = ko.observable();
    self.item = ko.observable();
    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
            if (self.items()[i].Id() === self.selectedItemId()) {
                self.item(self.items()[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(observableItems));
```

Comment: thanks mate, its a good idea to make any item observable, but its bit expensive, i was looking for a more lazy solution :). any way i will use this, hoping that ko 3.0 will bring some changes to this issue.

Comment: @dafriskymonkey not to worry.  Alternative for you if needed.